# make without rebuilding everything everytime

Tags: ros, performance, compilation, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my package I defined a library which is linked to my executable.. the cmakelists file looks like this:

```
...
rosbuild_add_library(mylib src/lib_src.cpp) #in the real cmake I have lot of sources in the library
rosbuild_add_executable(myexe src/exe_src.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myexe mylib)
...
```

When I run make everything is compiled. But if I run make again, everything is compiled again, even if nothing was modified.

Is it possible to compile only the changed parts? In my case would be fine to recompile the changed executable without recompiling the unchanged (and huge) library.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48822/make-without-rebuilding-everything-everytime/) by [Francesco Sacchi](https://answers.ros.org/users/3259/francesco-sacchi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 203 on 2012-11-21

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-22**:
Make should only compile your code if something changed. Without more information it's hard to guess a reason for the recompilation of everything.

**Comment by [Francesco Sacchi](https://answers.ros.org/users/3259/francesco-sacchi/) on 2012-11-22**:
Happy to hear that I am not expecting strange things :D
which kind of information should I provide to help the debug?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-22**:
For instance the actual snapshot in CMakeLists.txt you are using, not just something simplified. Also watch your clock and check the modification dates of your files. Are they maybe in the future?

**Comment by [Francesco Sacchi](https://answers.ros.org/users/3259/francesco-sacchi/) on 2012-11-22**:
heres my cmakelists: https://gist.github.com/4131480
timestamps are ok..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Finally, after hours I have an answer..

The problem is in the cfg files.

You must be sure that the filename matches the third parameter of the last line of the file, the one with the exit statement.

For example if the last line is:

```
exit(gen.generate(PACKAGE, "dummy", "myNameIsImportant"))
```

the file name must be *myNameIsImportant.cfg*

I did not find this information in the documentation/tutorials...

---

Originally posted by [Francesco Sacchi](https://answers.ros.org/users/3259/francesco-sacchi/) with karma: 203 on 2012-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 12

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-22**:
Good work! Feel free to add this information to the wiki and tutorials.

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2012-11-22**:
Yes, excellent find!